# printing nothing in string class array in c++ even though I can access individual elements

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I cannot print the string str2[i].a even though I can print the same in str1[i].a
I am getting the individual characters in the string as I print them by the index values
I can also print the str1[i].a string that I had entered before
Thanks!!

```
     #include <iostream>
     #include <vector>
     #include <string>

     using namespace std;

        class st
     {
        public:
           string a;
           int col;

     }str1[200],str2[200];


     int main()
    {
        int i=0,j=0,num,l=0,len=0;
        string str;

        for(i=0;;i++)
       {
           cin>>num;

           str1[i].col=num;

           if(str1[i].col==0)
                break;

           cin>>str1[i].a;

           cout<<str1[i].a; // I get string entered before                    

      }



      for(i=0;;i++)
      {   
             if(str1[i].col==0)
                  break;

             len = str1[i].a.size()-1;

             //cout << len << endl;

             l=0,j=0;

             for(;;)
            {

                 str2[i].a[l]=str1[i].a[j];
                 l++;
                 j=((j+str1[i].col)%len);

                 if(j==0)
                   {
                      str2[i].a[l]=str1[i].a[len];
                      cout << str2[i].a[l];//I get the char assigned above
                      l++;
                      str2[i].a[l]='\n';
                      break;
                   }

             }


          cout << str2[i].a; // I get nothing after I print
          cout << str2[i].a[0];// I get the required character of string
          cout << str2[i].a[5];//I get the required character of string
          cout << str2[i].a[8];//I get the required character of string
         }



       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: What happens if you go out of bounds of your array of strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you forget to do is to preallocate the buffer for your second string. It is only safe to assign a value to a character in an `std::string` if that string has at least that many characters (in other words, `str2.a[2] = 'a'` is safe is `std2.a` has a length of at least three, but is not safe if it has any smaller length). In your case none of the `str2`s is ever assigned anything, so they are all empty and have length of `0`.

One solution would be to preallocate your string in advance, but even better, since you only write characters to the end, use `push_back` instead of square brackets, as in

```
str2[i].push_back(str1[i].a[j]);
```

instead of

```
str2[i].a[l]=str1[i].a[j];
```

To explain why you can print individual characters, but not the entire string, note that what you do is technically an undefined behavior [1], I would assume that what it does is when you print the entire string, it looks at its length, sees that it is zero, and skips printing anything, but when you print individual characters, it looks at the buffer it allocated for the string (which is probably of non-zero size, to make early `push_back`s effective), and sees the changes you made to them.

[1] http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%5B%5D/, see in particular:

> If pos is less than the string length, the function never throws
>   exceptions (no-throw guarantee). If pos is equal to the string length,
>   the const-version never throws exceptions (no-throw guarantee).
>   Otherwise, it causes **undefined behavior**.

Comment: thanks for an amazing explanation which is simple but explains everything